# Animating button MUI with Hover

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Button component={Link} variant="text" to={link.path} sx={{ color: "#fff",'&:hover':{transform: 'translateY(-0.25em);'}}}>{link.label}</Button>
```

This is what I have tried so far with no sucsess
Is it possible to have &:hover in sx or do I have to create a style class in MUI?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use pseudo-selectors in the sx prop

Per MUI documentation

### Superset of CSS

As part of the prop, you can use any regular CSS too: child or pseudo-selectors, media queries, raw CSS values, etc. Here are a few examples:

Using pseudo selectors:

```
<Box
  sx={{
    // some styles
    ":hover": {
      boxShadow: 6,
    },
  }}
>
```